# jstree and Rails asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jstree

I am using the jstree (https://www.jstree.com/) jQuery library.  Works fine in development but in production all the standard background CSS breaks. The css calls the background icons from `/app-assets/32px.png` etc.  These files are in my `/app/assets/images` and even added them to my pre-compile but none of them load (throw 404 errors).

I suspect the issue is that I deploy to production Rails is pre-compiling the images and when the jstree css calls `url("32px.png")` the server calls `/app-assets/32px.png` which will always fail because the server is expecting the `/app-assets/32px-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.png` precompiled asset pipeline url.

I can manually dump the icon files in the public folder and hack the css but the JS seem to still trigger code for the old path.  Can I get JS tree to reference the Rails asset pipeline urls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ended up being the CSS which calls for the background to be `url("32px.png")` and in the Rails world that is relative to the pre-compiled CSS that is under /assets/...

I placed my jstree images in the static /public folder and then changed the CSS to `url("/32px.png")` so that jstree loads them absolute from root.

There is an option to use `image-url("32px.png")` but the jstree JS fails when it tried to load the images as it tries to still load the relative path and I saw some double loading of the image files etc.  I gave up on that and opted for the first solution.

Hope this helps someone down the road.